# How can I run my project on IOS device.?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mobile, .app

I am very new to IOS. I have developed one application in xcode and I want to run this app with  my iPhone device. HOw can I run this app in my mobile. PLease provide the steps to generate .app /IPA file and provide details that how can I run this app in my device. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Firstly, you need Mac for that. If you use Mac OS with Hackintosh, it won't detect device. And for running your project, select device and run.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at this:

[ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment.html)

I notice the other tutorial linked follows what I think of as the "old" way. With Xcode 4 you really don't need to do all those steps manually, use the Xcode organiser window and allow it to do all the steps for you. It is much easier.